# Visual Studio Windows Application - Show numbers in label

Tags: c#

I'm trying to make a simple incremental game.
I have a **button** to "build a hut". Basically, add 1 to an int value every time it's pressed. I want to then show in a label how many huts were built. But the label1.Text only accepts string values.

However, when I convert the integer .ToString, it doesn't work. It keeps the number at 1 and doesn't up it.

```
public void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int numberofhuts = 0;
    numberofhuts++;
    label1.Text = numberofhuts;
}
```

That's what it looks like. Any help would be super appreciated.

Comment: Have you been taught about the scope of variables? For example, if you declare `numberofhuts` inside of your method, then that variable will be recreated each time the method is called. If you want the value to persist, you need to store it elsewhere. By the way, what type of app is this? Web Forms? Win Forms? By the way, normal C# convention is to camelCase local variables, so that should be `numberOfHuts`. It makes the code more readable, which other developers working with your code will appreciate even if you don't.

Comment: Every time this button code runs, it does three things: (1) allocate a spot to store a number, (2) increment that number, (3) set the label text to that number.  If you do #1 *every time*, how will the number ever change?

Comment: @davedno C# does not have a concept of global variables, so suggesting that can be misleading. If you meant a [field](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/fields), then please say that instead. However, a field may not resolve this problem, because we don't know the lifecycle of the class this is in. That's why I would have held off before suggesting such an an approach. I suggest you remove your comment until we have additional information.

Comment: @mason Agreed, plus "a part of your parameters" doesn't make sense in this context. The method signature is that of an event handler, and can't be changed, and that wouldn't solve anything anyway.

Comment: @amy you know you can apply a number of custom parameters to an event handler....Right?

Comment: @davedno The event handler signature cannot be changed from the `EventHandler` delegate.

Comment: @mason you're making a mountain out of a mole hill. The way the handler is currently constructed the label will always show '1'. If that variable is passed in a parameter to the event handler or it is a FIELD of the class, his problem would be solved and he would see his label increment on button click.

Comment: @davedno I am not making a mountain out of a mole hill. We do not know with certain what the lifecycle of the class is. If it is a field in a Web Forms page for example (and this code could easily be Web Forms) then that field will get reset every time the page loads, and thus you're back at the same problem. So it's not enough to just say "make it a field". And "make it a global variable" has no meaning, since C# doesn't have a global variable concept.

Comment: @HereticMonkey I have rolled back your edit. We do not know with certainty that this in Windows Forms, so it'd be inappropriate for us to make that assumption on the asker's behalf. We need to await additional clarification.

Comment: @mason Fair enough, although with Visual Studio Windows Application in the title, combined with `public void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)` strongly suggests Windows Forms (WPF & UWP using `private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)` by default).

Comment: @HereticMonkey That exact code would look perfectly at place in Web Forms as well. Visual Studio can be used to build Web Forms apps, and Web Forms only runs on Windows (if you discount Mono). So Web Forms would be a fair assumption here. It's *probably* Win Forms, but instead of assuming we should wait for the OP to respond.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Right now, you reset the variable `numberofhuts` to zero, every time you click the button (as others have pointed out). So you need to do one of the following two things:

1. Move the variable to a broader scope (i.e. move it outside the button click.function)
2. Use the label text as a starting point for your increment.

The second approach is probably not the best, as this requires some sort of mechanism to ensure that the label text is always numeric. So you could do something like this:

```
public partial class MyForm : Form
{
    // Constructor (normally generated by Visual Studio)
    public MyForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    // Create, and initialize the variable outside the method.
    private int _numberOfHuts = 0;

    // When clicking the button, the variable is incremented
    // and the label is updated with the new value.
    private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
        _numberOfHuts++;
        label1.Text = numberOfHuts.ToString();
    }
}
```

Also, you should consider your naming. Names like `Button1` and `Label1` are poor choices, because they in no way indicate what they objects function are. Instead use something like `IncrementHutCount` for the button and `NumberOfHuts` for the label.

**Edit:** 
Note that the scope change I made, might not be broad enough. I just made the assumption that you only have a single form, which lives for the entire life span of the program. If this is not the case, you need to move it somewhere else.

Comment: You seem to be assuming this is Windows Forms...that's a dangerous assumption. I'd wait until the question is clear before answering with a specific approach.

Comment: @mason you are right, I should have mentioned what assumptions I made. I have tried to clarify this. Thanks.

Comment: @Noceo If the assumption is that this is WinForms, the `MyForm` class should inherit from `Form` to avoid confusion.

Comment: @Amy you are correct. It should also be a partial class. I have updated the sample.